Error while trying to create API Helper object for ETABS using Python
So I'm working on a python code to connect to ETABS API and extract and write information from/to the model.
The issue I'm having is that the code wont run because it gives the following error:
Error creating ETABS helper object: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string
Here's an extract from the code I'm working with:
import os
import sys
import comtypes.client

AttachToInstance = False

SpecifyPathETABS = True

SpecifyPathSAP2000 = True

ETABSProgramPath = R'C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\ETABS 22\ETABS.exe'

SAP2000ProgramPath = R'C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\SAP2000 22\SAP2000.exe'

#set it to the desired path of your model folder
APIPath = R'~path to model location~'

#full path to the ETABS model
ModelPath = APIPath + os.sep + 'model.EDB'

#create API helper object for ETABS
try:
    helper = comtypes.client.CreateObject('ETABSv1.Helper')
    helper = helper.QueryInterface(comtypes.gen.ETABSv1.cHelper)
except (OSError, comtypes.COMError) as e:
    print(f"Error creating ETABS helper object: {e}")
    sys.exit(-1)

I've tried loading ETABSv1.dll into registry using regsvr32, but got an error.. guess it's not the correct file to load to registry.
Don't know what else to try to fix this.

According to the help file CSI API ETABS v1:
The Remote API, used to start and/or connect to a running instance of
ETABS on a Remote Computer, has been disabled with the release of
ETABS v22.0.0. API functions listed below will return an error code
when called:

cHelper.CreateObjectHost
cHelper.CreateObjectHostPort
cHelper.CreateObjectProgIDHost
cHelper.CreateObjectProgIDHostPort
cHelper.GetObjectHost
cHelper.GetObjectHostPort

